# C# Assimp lib can not get index information

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx, index-buffer

I am using Assimp for C#.I Import fbx files. I am trying to render polygon containing files with index buffer. I try to get them like:

```
    var meshes = meshFile.Meshes;

    foreach (Assimp.Mesh mesh in meshes)
    {
        List<Vertex> meshFileVerticesList = new List<Vertex>();

        if (mesh.HasVertices)
        {...
            if (mesh.HasVertices)
                {
               ...
                }

                Indices = mesh.GetShortIndices(); //I thought this will give to me something like 0,1,2  2,3,0 so on
        }

    }
```

I get the result for Indices: `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14....`

if I manually do: `Indices = new short[] { 0,1,2  2,3,0 }` i see a face.

How can I correctly get index data ? Or there is no index data in fbx(?)